# List items which are not in where clause and not in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a list of usernames which need to be created. I can query the table to find out what ones exist, but how do I query what items from my list do not exist?

ie.

```
select username from aspnet_Users where UserName in (a,b,c,d, etc)
```

but if only `a` and `d` exist, what SQL can I use to return `b` and `c`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
-- Included a CTE here just so this example is runnable; 
-- You don't need it in your query
WITH aspnet_Users (UserName) AS
(
    SELECT 'a' UNION
    SELECT 'd'
)
SELECT
    n.UserName
FROM
    aspnet_Users e
RIGHT JOIN 
    (VALUES ('b'), ('c')) AS n(UserName)
    ON 
    e.UserName = n.UserName
```

Basically you join your existing table to the usernames you're checking, and only return the results where there was no match.

Results:

```
UserName
--------
b
c

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: thanks, your answer pointed me in the right direction. Used this:    (select 'a 'union 'b' etc) except (select username from aspnet_Users where username in ('a','b','c','d')), which if a and c already exists it returns b and d. edit: sorry can't get code blocks to work